# Use docstrings to list tests in py.test

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Here is a simple test file:

```
# test_single.py
def test_addition():
    "Two plus two is still four"
    assert 2 + 2 == 4

def test_addition2():
    "One plus one is still two"
    assert 1 + 1 == 2
```

The default output in py.test is like

```
$ py.test test_single.py -v
[...]
test_single.py::test_addition PASSED
test_single.py::test_addition2 PASSED
```

I would like to have

```
Two plus two is still four PASSED
One plus one is still two PASSED
```

i.e. use the docstrings as descriptions for the tests.

I tried to use a customization in a `conftest.py` file:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.tryfirst
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call, __multicall__):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    rep = __multicall__.execute()
    if rep.when == "call":
        extra = item._obj.__doc__.strip()
        rep.nodeid =  extra
    return rep
```

that is close, but it repeats the filename on every line:

```
$ py.test test_single.py
======================================================================================== test session starts =========================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.7 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.6.4
plugins: greendots, osxnotify, pycharm
collected 2 items

test_single.py
And two plus two is still four .
test_single.py
And one plus one is still two .

====================================================================================== 2 passed in 0.11 seconds ======================================================================================
```

How can I avoid the lines with `test_single.py` in the output, or maybe print it only once?

Looking into the source of py.test and some of its plugins did not help.

I am aware of the [pytest-spec](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-spec) plugin, but that uses the function's name as a description. I don't want to write `def test_two_plus_two_is_four()`.

Comment: Did you look at pytest-spec's source code? It seems you could use that as a starting point for your own plugin (pytest-spec's code is really short).

Comment: "I don't want to write def test_two_plus_two_is_four()" - why? This is a meaningful method name, `test_addition` is not. Names like `test_addition2` are telltale signs that your naming convention might need to be improved.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoOliveira, I did have a look there, but I thought that the customization in `conftest.py` would be simpler.

Comment: @oefe - I get your point. It's more a matter of taste as these method names get longer and longer. Maybe I am just spoiled by rspec where you can write `it "adds one and one correctly"` and that is what you get in the output of the test run.

Comment: What's the problem with long method names here? You never have to call a test method explicitly, so you are typing each test name exactly once. Sure, `"adds one and one correctly"` reads a bit nicer than `test_adds_one_and_one_correctly`, but is this worth breaking the convention?

Answer (score 25):

To expand on my comment to @michael-wan's answer: to achive something similar to `specplugin` put into `conftest.py`:

```
def pytest_itemcollected(item):
    par = item.parent.obj
    node = item.obj
    pref = par.__doc__.strip() if par.__doc__ else par.__class__.__name__
    suf = node.__doc__.strip() if node.__doc__ else node.__name__
    if pref or suf:
        item._nodeid = ' '.join((pref, suf))
```

and the `pytest` output of

```
class TestSomething:
"""Something"""

def test_ok(self):
    """should be ok"""
    pass
```

will look like

[image: py.test screen grab]

If you omit docstrings class/func names will be used.

Comment: This is seriously unsafe: see https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4701#issuecomment-460293303

Answer (score 9):

I was missing `rspec in ruby` for python. So, based on the plugin `pytest-testdox.`, I have written similar one which takes doc strings as report message. You can check it out [pytest-pspec](https://github.com/gowtham-sai/pytest-pspec). [image]

Answer (score 5):

For a plugin that (I think) does what you want out of the box, check out [pytest-testdox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-testdox).

It provides a friendly formatted list of each test function name, with `test_` stripped, and underscores replaced with spaces, so that the test names are readible. It also breaks up the sections by test file.

This is what the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I think the OP asked for, but it doesn't print the docstring.

Answer (score 2):

@Matthias Berth, you can try to use pytest_itemcollected

```
def pytest_itemcollected(item):
""" we just collected a test item. """
    item.setNodeid('' if item._obj.__doc__ is None else item._obj.__doc__.strip() )
```

and modify pydir/Lib/site-packages/pytest-2.9.1-py2.7.egg/_pytest/unittest.py
add the following function to the TestCaseFunction class

```
def setNodeid(self, value):
    self._nodeid = value
```

and the result will be :

```
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- D:\Python27\python.exe
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: E:\workspace\satp2\atest\testcase\Search\grp_sp, inifile:
plugins: html-1.8.0, pep8-1.0.6
collecting 0 itemsNone
collected 2 items
Two plus two is still four <- sut_amap3.py PASSED
One plus one is still two <- sut_amap3.py PASSED
```

[image]
by the way when you are using pytest-html
you can use the pytest_runtest_makereport function you make and it will  generate the report with the name you customized.
hope this helps.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to modify `pytest` sources, put this into your `conftest.py` in the project root: `def pytest_itemcollected(item):
        if item._obj.__doc__:             item._nodeid = item.obj.__doc__.strip()`

This way the behavior _might_ _not_ break on future updates to `pytest`

Comment: I am using same and can see the result. But xml report is not showing classname. It's empty string. What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do the same but in a simpler way, preferably without an external plugin to do more than needed and also avoiding changing the `nodeid` as it could break other things

I came up with the following solution:

`test_one.py`

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_one():
    """ The First test does something """
    logger.info("One")

def test_two():
    """ Now this Second test tests other things """
    logger.info("Two")

def test_third():
    """ Third test is basically checking crazy stuff """
    logger.info("Three")
```

`conftest.py`

```
import pytest
import inspect

@pytest.mark.trylast
def pytest_configure(config):
    terminal_reporter = config.pluginmanager.getplugin('terminalreporter')
    config.pluginmanager.register(TestDescriptionPlugin(terminal_reporter), 'testdescription')

class TestDescriptionPlugin:

    def __init__(self, terminal_reporter):
        self.terminal_reporter = terminal_reporter
        self.desc = None

    def pytest_runtest_protocol(self, item):
        self.desc = inspect.getdoc(item.obj)

    @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
    def pytest_runtest_logstart(self, nodeid, location):
        if self.terminal_reporter.verbosity == 0:
            yield
        else:
            self.terminal_reporter.write('\n')
            yield
            if self.desc:
                    self.terminal_reporter.write(f'\n{self.desc} ')
```

Running with `--verbose`

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-5.4.1.dev62+g2d9dac95e, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- C:\Users\Victor\PycharmProjects\pytest\venv\Scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\Victor\PycharmProjects\pytest, inifile: tox.ini
collecting ... collected 3 items


test_one.py::test_one 
The First test does something  PASSED                                    [ 33%]

test_one.py::test_two 
Now this Second test tests other things  PASSED                          [ 66%]

test_one.py::test_third 
Third test is basically checking crazy stuff  PASSED                     [100%]

============================== 3 passed in 0.07s ==============================
```

Running with `--log-cli-level=INFO`

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-5.4.1.dev62+g2d9dac95e, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Users\Victor\PycharmProjects\pytest, inifile: tox.ini
collected 3 items


test_one.py::test_one 
The First test does something  
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
INFO     test_one:test_one.py:7 One
PASSED                                                                   [ 33%]

test_one.py::test_two 
Now this Second test tests other things  
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
INFO     test_one:test_one.py:11 Two
PASSED                                                                   [ 66%]

test_one.py::test_third 
Third test is basically checking crazy stuff  
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
INFO     test_one:test_one.py:15 Three
PASSED                                                                   [100%]

============================== 3 passed in 0.07s ==============================
```

The plugin in `conftest.py` is probably simple enough for anyone to customize according to their own needs.